# Enzyme/Jest failing test for props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that gets accepts a prop, called `license`. I am trying to test a couple of things but I am failing.

Basically, I want to check that if my property is present, then show a specific element with `class` or another component. I have a few.

Here is my test, in which I try to check that if I have the `prop.license.expiredAt`, is true, then the Icon component should be present:

```
  it('expects to show LicenseInfo if license prop is true', () => {
    const props = {
      license: {
        clientId: '01',
        expiredAt: 1551391198000,
        isValid: true,     }
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <LicenseInfo license={props.license}>
        <div>test</div>
      </LicenseInfo>
    );
    const html = wrapper.find(<Icon icon="test" />).html();
    expect(html).toContain(props.license.expiry);
  });
});
```

But I get an error:

```
 FAIL  src/LicenseInfo/__tests__/index.test.tsx (8.156s)
  ● LicenseInfo Component › expects to show LicenseInfo if license prop is true

    Method “html” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      30 |       </LicenseInfo>
      31 |     );
    > 32 |     const html = wrapper.find(<Icon icon="test" />).html();
         |                                                     ^
      33 |     expect(html).toContain(props.license);
      34 |   });
      35 | });

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1875:17)
      at ShallowWrapper.html (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1032:21)
      at Object.it (src/shared/common/components/panel/LicenseInfo/__tests__/index.test.tsx:32:53)
```

And here is my component:

```
/* eslint-disable react/default-props-match-prop-types */
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import ILicense from 'dto/ILicense';

import PageHeader from 'components/PageHeader';
import Icon from 'components/Icon';

export interface Props {
  license: ILicense;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const LicenseInfo = <T extends object>({ license }: Props & T) =>(
  <Fragment>
    {license ? (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container mt-5">
          <PageHeader className="font-weight-bold">License Information</PageHeader>
          <div className="container bg-white">
            <div className="py-5 ml-3">
              {license.expiredAt ? (
                <div className="mb-5">
                  <Icon icon="check" className="fa-lg text-success" />
                  Your License is Valid
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="mb-5">
                  <Icon icon="exclamation-circle" className="fa-lg text-danger" />
                  YourLicense has expired
                </div>
              )}
              <table className="table col-6">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Valid Until:</td>
                    <td className="font-weight-bold">
                      {moment(license.expiredAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    ) : null}
  </Fragment>
);

LicenseInfo.defaultProps = {
  clientId: '',
  expiredAt: null,
  isValid: false,
};

export default LicenseInfo;
```

I am really new to testing so, if I have forgotten something please ask and I will provide. I am struggling quite a bit and would like some help. An explanation of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Snapshot Testing to record the state rather than focusing on specific properties. just using

```
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

also `shallow` does not render the DOM of child components so maybe you want to use `mount` instead to be able to access the full DOM generated by the component (i.e using selectors). Might be that the properties you are trying to assert on Icons are just not rendered on a shallow rendering.

Comment: I read about snapshots, bit we decided against them... Aahhh of course. Completely forgotten about that.... I will try it, and upvote if that fixes it ... Thank you!!